# Prove that if $a>0\ then\ 1+a^9\le \frac1a+a^{10}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Prove that if $a>0\ then\ 1+a^9\le \frac1a+a^{10}$

I started off by moving every term to the left side of the inequality and multiplied every term by a since a>0 but not sure where to go after that. The hint given is to complete the square.

$a+a^{10}-a^{11}\le0$

Comment: @ Michelle Stasso if you like my answer, you can check on it.

Answer (score 1):

Factoring the expression you found, obtain
$$(a^{10}-1)(a-1) \geq 0 $$

that you must prove. Now as $a>0$, observe that if $a<1$ then $a^{10}<1$, so the two factors have the same sign, so the product is positive. Similarly, if $a>1$ also $a^{10}>1$ and the product is still positive. Done.